# why does my icon image not show up on window that i have created

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, icons

while i was making a window, i used .wm_iconbitmap(). it worked but the image showed as blank in the corner of the window. is this because of the size of the file? 
there wasn't an error in the code which led me to believe that it was to do with the image it's self.

i have tried resizing the image to as small as possible and tried using different images.

```
import tkinter
import os
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("my_window")
os.chdir("c:\\RILEYHQ\\my images")
top.wm_iconbitmap('my_icon.ico')
top.mainloop()
```

this results in a window with a title and an empty sheet of paper image as the icon

Comment: Icon image would mean the small icon that appears next to the Title.
Is that what you need or are you trying to post an image in the tkinter window?

Comment: Tried your code with Pythons `pyc.ico` without problems. Could it be something to do with your specific icon? Can you post a link to the icon file?

Comment: ParvBanks yes i am trying to make an icon not an image.

Comment: figbeam the image is on my computer so i don't know how i would send it to you